# How to make Derive work with a parameter other than x and how to invoke Derive in postfix notation?

Tags: pstricks, postscript

In my investigation `Derive` can only evaluate the derivative of function `f(x)` with respect to `x`. My attempt below does not produce the expected result because I try to find the derivative of `x(t)` and `y(t)` with respect to `t`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}

\def\x{sin(t)}
\def\y{cos(t)}

\def\xx{Derive(1,\x)}
\def\yy{Derive(1,\y)}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-.2,-2.2)(\dimexpr\psPiFour cm+.2cm,2.2)
    \psparametricplot{0}{TwoPi 2 mul}{\xx|\yy}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

- Can anybody here help me to let `Derive` also work with any variable such that my project [here (click)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175874/19356) can be easily done without having to manually calculate the derivative of the given functions?
- How can we invoke `Derive` in postfix form? If it is possible then the first question can be solved  just by using `ED` as follows,

  ```
  <postfix expression in x>  1 Derive t /x ED
  ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `x` used for the derivative is hardcoded, see definition of `/EvalDerive` in the file `pst-algparser.pro`. So you must redefine some internal Postscript functions.

The less invasive redefinition I found was to change `/EvalVariable`, which is the only procedure actually accessing the `(x)`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\def\ChangeEvalVariable#1{%
  \pstVerb{tx@Derive begin
    /origEvalVariable /EvalVariable load def
    /EvalVariable { 2 index (#1) eq { (1) } { (0) } ifelse 4 -1 roll exch 6 2 roll } def
  end }%
}%
\def\ResetEvalVariable{%
  \pstVerb{tx@Derive begin
    /EvalVariable /origEvalVariable load def
    end }%
}%
\def\x{sin(t)}
\def\y{cos(t)}

\def\xx{Derive(1,\x)}
\def\yy{Derive(1,\y)}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-1.2,-1.2)(3.2,1.2)
    \ChangeEvalVariable{t}
    \psparametricplot{0}{Pi}{\xx|\yy}
    \ResetEvalVariable
    \psplot{0}{Pi}{Derive(1,sin(x))}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You cannot use `Derive` for a Postscript expression, because `Derive` actually calculates the derivative analytically by parsing the string representation of the function.