# Draw multiple curves at a constant distance from one another in asymptote

Tags: asymptote

In `asymptote`, I would like to draw arbitrary paths as in the following image, but with multiple colors.  In the example, the path shown in black is also drawn with two parallel red lines.  I would like to do the same thing but with green on the inner diameter and red on the outer diameter.  I need it to also work for arbitrary paths.

[image]

In the next image, I've created two pens using the `makepen` function.  The pen nibs are offset vertically in this example.  However, I want a solution where the distance between the red and green curves is constant regardless of the path slope (as in the above image).

```
unitsize(1inch);
path path1 = arc((0,0), 0.6, 0, 180);
path path2 = (-0.5,0){E}..{S}(0.5,0);
pen pen1 = makepen(shift(-0.5,-2)*unitsquare)+green;
pen pen2 = makepen(shift(-0.5,+1)*unitsquare)+red;
draw(path1, pen1);
draw(path1, pen2);
draw(path1, black);
draw(path2, pen1);
draw(path2, pen2);
draw(path2, black);
```

[image]

Do you have an idea for how to keep the constant distance between the red and green curves for arbitrary paths?

FYI - The first image is produced in `asymptote` by drawing a thick red line, then drawing a thin white line over it.

Comment: See the definition of `wheelpath` in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175968/484

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you @CharlesStaats for the link to your cool example code!  That's a nice usage of the `graph` package.  Adapting your example to my need gives the following result.  Hopefully I'm not breaking etiquette by answering my own question.

I'm still interested in an alternate simple solution using `pen` definitions.

```
unitsize(1inch);
import graph;
path pathA = (0,0){E}..{S}(1.0,0);
real offset = 0.05;
pair offsetPoint(real t) { return point(pathA, t) + offset*(rotate(90)*dir(pathA,t)); }
path pathB = graph(offsetPoint, 0, length(pathA), operator ..);
offset = -0.05;
path pathC = graph(offsetPoint, 0, length(pathA), operator ..);
draw(pathA);
draw(pathB, red);
draw(pathC, green);
```

[image]

Comment: You're not breaking etiquette; there's even a badge for that, and I was hoping you would. One minor quibble--it's not a great idea to call a variable `path3` since that's the type of a three-dimensional path.

Comment: Great point, I've edited the path names.

Answer (score 1):

Building on James's solution, I've modified the code using a higher order function such that the path is not hard coded in the offset function.

```
unitsize(1inch);
import graph;
path pathA = (0,0){E}..{S}(1.0,0);
typedef pair offsetFunction(real);
offsetFunction offsetPoint(path original_path, real d) {return new pair(real t) {return point(original_path, t) + d*(rotate(90)*dir(original_path,t));};};
path pathB = graph(offsetPoint(pathA, 0.05), 0, length(pathA), operator ..);
path pathC = graph(offsetPoint(pathA, -0.05), 0, length(pathA), operator ..);
draw(pathA);
draw(pathB, red);
draw(pathC, green);
```