# Drawing a tube around a function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm looking for a way to draw a tube around a function. I already defined my function (see code below). The distance between tube and function shoulb be equal in each point -> see for example arrows in the picture below.

I'm looking just for the tube outside, the arrows are just for explanation.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    domain=0:100,
    samples=100]

\addplot[BrickRed,domain=0:100,ultra  thick, no marks] {sin(x*5.34)+cos(x)};

\end{axis}          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output from the code above]

[image]

Comment: Apparently this must be a curves that has the same slope everywhere as the original curve but not the same curvature

Comment: Do you know, how to achieve this?

Comment: Not immediately. I've to cancel my statement about the slope as well...

Comment: Maybe ist there the possibility to set the thickness of the function graph (red) arbitrary?? This could solve the problem.

Comment: I guess this doesn't help you, but the question reminds me of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175874/how-to-make-the-length-of-a-car-moving-on-a-roller-coaster-track-remain-unchange :)

Comment: This is actually (difficult) differential geometry, involving solving a system of ordinary differential equations, in my point of view

Comment: @Christoph Looks like what I'm looking for, except the car and animation :)

Comment: Isn't there the possibility, to draw the same function really really fat and  deposit it in the background?

Comment: Draw it in fat color, then a little less fat in white and then the normal thickness in color (untested)

Comment: You can put `\addplot[double, double distance=15pt,domain=0:100, line width=1pt, no marks] {sin(x*5.34)+cos(x)};` before your actual plot (the `double` key does pretty much what @daleif suggested)

Comment: @Jake sorry, I took your answer. Hadn't seen in. I was looking in my own questions I had asked. Sorry

Comment: @Arne: No worries!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here you are...

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 2]
\begin{axis}[
hide axis,
domain=0:100,
samples=100]

\addplot[BrickRed,domain=0:100,ultra  thick, double=brown!40,double   distance=10pt, no marks] {sin(x*5.34)+cos(x)};
\addplot[BrickRed,domain=0:100,ultra  thick, no marks] {sin(x*5.34)+cos(x)};

\end{axis}          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]