# Beamer: How to represent movement of an object along a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, diagrams, tikz-styles, animations

Need to represent a moving car through a service center in beamer. A motion is depicted on the link [How to make the length of a car moving on a roller coaster track remain unchanged?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175874/how-to-make-the-length-of-a-car-moving-on-a-roller-coaster-track-remain-unchange). Need a similar type of format. The car needs to move to service center and then leave and this movement should go on.
[image]

I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}                 % Document class
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language
\mode<presentation>                     % Set options
{
    \usetheme{default}                    % Set theme
    \usecolortheme{rose}              % Set colors
    \usefonttheme{default}                % Set font theme
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % Set caption to be numbered
    }
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}

\begin{document}    
            \begin{frame}{Example}
            \begin{tikzpicture} 
            \draw[black, thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,2) node[pos=.5] {Service center};
            \draw[-stealth] (-3,1) -- (0,1) node[midway,above] {Car};
            \draw[-stealth] (3,1) -- (6,1) node[midway,above] {Car};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what you tried. Simple Do-it-for-me questions aren't that well received.

Comment: As per my understanding, tikz needs to be used. I am not very familiar with tikz, so didn't put mwe.

Comment: The TikZ user guide has a good tutorial at the start. It should at least enable you to draw a rectangle and two arrows.

Comment: I have added my tried part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @CarLaTeX's red sports car from https://github.com/TikZlings/Extravaganza2018/blob/main/samcarter/CarlaDriving/carlatex.pdf

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}                 % Document class
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}             % Set language
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\mode<presentation>                     % Set options
{
    \usetheme{default}                    % Set theme
    \usecolortheme{rose}              % Set colors
    \usefonttheme{default}                % Set font theme
    \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered] % Set caption to be numbered
    
}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}                  % For table rules
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{charter} % serif
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
 \usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}
    \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
    
\begin{document}
        \begin{frame}
        \transduration<1->{0} 
        \frametitle{Example \dots}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node[draw,rectangle,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm] (foo) at (current page.center) {Service center};
        \draw[-stealth] ([xshift=1cm]current page.west) -- (foo);
        \draw[-stealth] (foo) -- ([xshift=-1cm]current page.east);
        \foreach \x in {1,1.25,...,15}{
          \node<+>[xscale=-1] at ([xshift=\x cm]current page.west) {\includegraphics[width=1cm]{carlatex}};
        }
        \node[draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm] at (current page.center) {Service center};        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You probably kept the various packages from the OP's original code, but isn't only `tikz` really needed here?

Comment: @JasperHabicht yes, but too lazy to clean up

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is a big help.

Comment: @mathslove You're welcome!